# How to save a file from Supabase Storage using Node.js (converting blob to file)

Tags: node.js, blob, buffer, supabase

I am downloading media files (mainly images) from Supabase Storage using [`from.download()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-download) in NodeJS.

How can I save the Blob that is returned as a file on my local hard drive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a buffer from the Blob and save that on your hard drive.

**A working example:**
(Note: If you are not working with NodeJS ESM modules, you must use `require` instead of `import`)

```
import fs from 'fs'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const supabase = createClient(yourSupaseUrl, yourSupabaseKey)

const fileName = 'some-file.png'
const filePath = 'some-folder/' + fileName
const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
        .from('storage-name')
        .download(filePath)

const blob = data;
const buffer = Buffer.from( await blob.arrayBuffer() );
await fs.promises.writeFile(fileName, buffer);
```

**Links that helped me:**

- StackOverflow answer in [Save video blob to filesystem electron/node js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60468824/3763660)
- Supabase docs about [from.download()](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-download)